# Can't withdraw CGPoint Values from A mutableArray of NSValue

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray, cgpoint, nsvalue

I made an NSMUtableArray of CGpoints and I stored them by subclassing as NSValue, but I cant get the values out. here I what I did.

```
 CGPoint graphPoint;
    NSMutableArray *pointValues = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for( int x =0;x<5; x++)
    {
    NSDictionary* xValue = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:x] forKey:@"X"];
    graphPoint.x =x;
    graphPoint.y = [CalculatorBrain runProgram: self.graphingPoint usingVariableValues:xValue];

    [pointValues addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:graphPoint]];

}
```

I tried using this to get the values but I just get null back

```
for( int x=0; x<5; x++) {
NSValue *val = [pointValues objectAtIndex:x];
CGPoint point = [val CGpointValue];
NSLog(@"Points = %@", point);
}
```

Comment: It's a miracle that code doesn't crash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't print a `CGPoint` using the `%@` format specifier, as it is not an object. Instead, use [`NSStringFromCGPoint()`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSStringFromCGPoint):

```
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(myPoint));
```

Comment: seems to work but I get an implicit declaration warning for NSStringFromPoint, is that okay?

Comment: @TerrelGibson did you include UIKit / AppKit? Your code will probably still work fine, but that warning is never good.

Comment: do I just do #include "UIKit / AppKit" because I get a error saying filename not found

Comment: @TerrelGibson no, you include `UIKit/UIKit.h` (for iOS), or `AppKit/AppKit.h` (for mac).

Comment: @JoshCaswell good point, thanks for pointing that out, fixed.